# Искажается картинка при display: flex;

Tags: html, css

В конечном результате должно получится [так](https://prnt.sc/qhoxv6). При верстки второй части возникла проблема - `display: flex` искажает [картинку](https://prnt.sc/qhoyta).

Как исправить?

```css
.header-office {
  display: flex;
}

.header-mark {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.header-office__text {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-office">
  <img src="img/mark.png" alt="Mark" class="header-mark">
  <div class="header-office__text">Наши офисы</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для класса header-mark добавить это:

```
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
```